# Probability of pulling from urn.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If there is an urn containing n element, indexed from $1$ to $n$, what is the probability of pulling the $k^{th}$ on the $k^{th}$ try? Should I have a an event $A = A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap An$, where $A_i$ means that it $i$ indexed ball was pulled at the $i^{th}$ try? I'm confused

Comment: Can you determine the answer for $k=1$?

Comment: Are we using replacement? Also the event $A$ you defined reduces to the event where you pick everything in numerical order: picking $1$ first AND picking $2$ second AND...

Comment: The chance of pulling any one particular element in a single pull (the kth element on pull k) is simply 1/n. Are you asking about a sequence of pulls with/without replacement, or the probability of ever succeeding in a series of trials?

Comment: In related problems, you might be asking what the expected number of pulls result in having pulled the ball with the same number as the number try you are on.  That can be found easily with linearity of expectation to be $\frac{1}{n}$ times the number of pulls you do, in the case of pulling $n$ times, that would simplify to $1$.  Also related, the probability of having drawn no balls on their respective turns (*assuming no replacement*) would be $\dfrac{!n}{n!}$ where $!n$ is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  (*With replacement $(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$*)

Comment: On the other hand, the event $A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_n$ would correspond to having drawn the correct ball on each and every pull and would occur with probability $\frac{1}{n!}$ if no replacement (*or $\frac{1}{n^n}$ if with replacement*) which doesn't sound like something you would be interested in.

Comment: so if I pulled a ball I can't put it back

Comment: That $A$ event then isn't what I'm looking for. I've also found a solved version of the same problem but I don't understand it. It says the same kind of $A$ event, and that its probability is $$P(A_1)P_{A_1}(A2)... = \frac{(n-k)!}{n!}$$, using conditional probability. Now I'm confused how that works.

Comment: $\frac{(n-k)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{(n-1)}\cdot \frac{1}{(n-2)}\cdots \frac{1}{(n-k+1)}$ is the probability that when drawing $k$ balls, all $k$ of them were numbered the same as the turn in which they were drawn.  You get that very simply by multiplying at each step by the probability of having drawn the same numbered ball for that step given that in all previous steps you had done the same.  Note that when $k=n$, i.e. you draw all $n$ balls, the result is as mentioned before as being $\frac{(n-n)!}{n!}=\frac{0!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: Note that the probability of having drawn the $k$'th ball on the $k$'th try is as mentioned already $\frac{1}{n}$.  The probability of having drawn the $k$'th ball on the $k$'th try *given that all earlier tries also resulted in having pulled the ball for that try* will be $\frac{1}{n-k+1}$, seen by noting that in such an event there remain $n-k+1$ balls of which one of them is guaranteed to still be the correctly numbered ball for the current try.